# Single line thread/sequenced execution of formulas in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a simple macro function in VBA for Excel to extract text appearing in a particular location in an HTML document, first retrieving the HTML document from a URL value in another cell.  The macro function itself is not important, except for the fact that it sends an HTTP request and creates an HTML file object, which I fear will cause Excel to crash if I paste, say, a column of 100 or more URLs and it starts trying to calculate all the values at once.  I can see that it stops and churns for a moment if I drag the formula down 10 cells where there is already a column of URLs.  Is there a setting to force Excel to calculate one formula at a time, so that it may take longer but is less likely to freeze up or crash?

Update: I incorporated a static collection variable into the function to at least avoid repeated slowdowns retrieving the same HTML in the same worksheet:

```
Function GetUSPatentAbstract(ByVal url As String) As String
    Static colAbstract As New Collection
    Dim abstract As String
    On Error Resume Next
    abstract = colAbstract(url)
```

`If there is no abstract for the URL in the collection yet, then it is retrieved:

```
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Dim description As String
        Dim abstractStart As Long
        Dim abstractEnd As Long
        Dim abstractLength As Long

        Set html_doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        xml_obj.Open "GET", url, False
        xml_obj.send
        html_doc.body.innerhtml = xml_obj.responseText
        Set xml_obj = Nothing


        description = html_doc.body.innertext
        abstractStart = InStr(description, "Abstract") + 8
        abstractEnd = InStr(description, "Inventors:")
        abstractLength = abstractEnd - abstractStart

        abstract = Mid(description, abstractStart, abstractLength)

        colAbstract.Add Item:=abstract, Key:=url

     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     GetUSPatentAbstract = abstract


End Function
```

Comment: Maybe set calculations to manual, then roll down the formula and turn calculations on again (automatic). Maybe excel will do one linear run through the formulas.

Comment: You can adjust your VBA such that it won't run repeat fetches for the same URL, for example by storing the results in a Scripting Dictionary with the URL as the key.  When a repeat request comes in for the same URL it can then use the cached result instead of re-running the complete process.

Comment: Bas, that would be similar to pasting in the column of URLs with the formulas that operate on the URLs already filled in, which is how I envision using the spreadsheet.  Essentially I want to get a bunch of patent abstracts to appear automatically to expedite a high-level review.  Tim that is good to know, but in this case the trouble is the URL's are all different.

Comment: As an update, I just got 246 abstracts to appear without Excel crashing.  It was processing for a little while.  I am wary of causing problems if I try to do that regularly, but I am kind of a newbie at running spreadsheet calculations and maybe my concerns are unwarranted.

Comment: Tim in fact I found your idea helpful to avoid re-executing the formulas that have already been executed; comment edited to add code. Instead of using a scripting dictionary I built a static collection into the formula and the formula checks to see if the collection already has a value for the URL before sending an HTTP request.